# Twitter api python - max number of objects

Tags: scripting, twitter, python

so I am calling the twitter api:

```
    openurl = urllib.urlopen("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&contributor_details&include_rts=true&screen_name="+user+"&count=3600")
```

and it returns some long file like:

```
[{"entities":{"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/Hd1ubDVX","indices":[115,135],"display_url":"amzn.to\/tPSKgf","expanded_url":"http:\/\/amzn.to\/tPSKgf"}]},"coordinates":null,"truncated":false,"place":null,"geo":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"retweet_count":2,"favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"user":{"contributors_enabled":false,"lang":"en","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/151701304\/theme14.gif","favourites_count":0,"profile_text_color":"333333","protected":false,"location":"North America","is_translator":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/151701304\/theme14.gif","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1642783876\/idB005XNC8Z4_normal.png","name":"User Interface Books","profile_link_color":"009999","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/ReleasedBooks\/genres","utc_offset":-28800,"description":"All new user interface and graphic design book releases posted on their publication day","listed_count":11,"profile_background_color":"131516","statuses_count":1189,"following":false,"profile_background_tile":true,"followers_count":732,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a2.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1642783876\/idB005XNC8Z4_normal.png","default_profile":false,"geo_enabled":false,"created_at":"Mon Sep 20 21:28:15 +0000 2010","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"efefef","show_all_inline_media":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false,"friends_count":1,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"eeeeee","screen_name":"User","id_str":"193056806","verified":false,"id":193056806,"default_profile_image":false,"profile_use_background_image":true,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)"},"possibly_sensitive":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"created_at":"Thu Nov 17 00:01:45 +0000 2011","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"retweeted":false,"source":"\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/ReleasedBooks\/genres\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003EBook Releases\u003C\/a\u003E","id_str":"136957158075011072","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"id":136957158075011072,"contributors":null,"text":"Digital Media: Technological and Social Challenges of the Interactive World - by William Aspray - Scarecrow Press. http:\/\/t.co\/Hd1ubDVX"},{"entities":{"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/GMCzTija","indices":[119,139],"display_u
```

Well,
the different objects are slit into tables and dictionaries and I want to extract the different parts but to do this I have to know how many objects the file has:

example:

```
[{1:info , 2:info}][{1:info , 2:info}][{1:info , 2:info}][{1:info , 2:info}]
```

so to extract the info from 1 in the first table I would:

```
[0]['1']
>>>>info
```

But to extract it from the last object in the table I need to know how many object the table has.

This is what my code looks like:

```
    table_timeline = json.loads(twitter_timeline)

    table_timeline_inner = table_timeline[x]
    lines = 0
    while lines < linesmax:
        in_reply_to_user_id = table_timeline_inner['in_reply_to_status_id_str']
        lines += 1
```

So how do I find the value of the last object in this table?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're looking for, but to get the last item in a python list, use an index of -1. For example,

```
>>> alist = [{'position': 'first'}, {'position': 'second'}, {'position': 'third'}]
>>> print alist[-1]['position']
{'position': 'third'}
>>> print alist[-1]['position']
third
```